# Viewing SYS schema tables of JBoss EDS/Teiid VDB

Tags: jdbc, jboss, odbc, microstrategy, teiid

Can someone help me understand how to expose the SYS schema objects of a JBoss Teiid Virtual Database when connected via an ODBC-JDBC bridge ?

The client is connecting to ODBC side of the bridge and the JDBC side of it is connecting to the Virtual Database (VDB) running on the JBoss SOA server.

With the current setting only the tables and columns modeled thru the JBoss Studio's Teiid Designer are exposed but not the SYS schema and its underlying objects. Client App is Microstrategy BI application.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to traverse all metadata from all used data sources using native JDBC JAVA API.

Answer (score -1):

I am new to Teiid and had the similar question.

When you create the VDB with JBoss designer you can specify which models will be exposed to the client applications. As a good practice, only View models are exposed and Source models are not. As a result, querying against the System tables of the VDB will only show you the metadata within the View models, which will be a subset of the metadata in the underlying data sources.

Hope this helps.